# making user dir a sym link to another drive

Tags: windows-7, windows-7-x64

I am building a brand new box with a fresh install of win7

I am installing windows on a sdd and the rest on a raid

I would like to move the c:\users to the raid.

Has anyone made c:\users a symlink to another drive.

I am thinking that would be the cleanest way.

Not sure how to , because i am sure the dir will probably be locked

Answer (score 0):

found it

http://lifehacker.com/5467758/move-the-users-directory-in-windows-7